# Finding basis for vector space of polynomials with complex coefficients

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, vector-spaces

> Find a basis for the vector space over $\Bbb C$ of polynomials $p(z)$ of degree at most $4$ with coefficients in $\mathbb C$ satisfying $p(z) = p(−z)$ for all $z\in\mathbb C$ and $p(−2) = 0.$

So I've found a basis but I don't think I'm correct since I only used the first condition. If I set
$$p(z) = p(-z)$$
then I get
$$az^4+bz^3+cz^2+dz+e = az^4-bz^3+cz^2-dz+e$$
$$bz^3+dz=0$$
which suggests that the basis is $\{z,z^3\}$ which seems too simple and does not require the second condition at all. Am I correct or have I made a mistake somewhere? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a mistake. If $p(z)=p(-z)$, then $bz^3+dz$ is the null polynomial, and therefore$$p(z)=az^4+cz^2+e.$$and$$p(-2)=0\iff16a+4c+e=0\iff e=-16a-4c.$$So, your space is$$\{az^4+cz^2-16a-4c\mid a,c\in\Bbb C\},$$of which $\{z^4-16,z^2-4\}$ is a basis.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that two polynomials are equal if the coefficient of each $n$th degree term are equal, so the fact that
$$
az^4 + bz^3+cz^2+dz+e = az^4 -bz^3+cz^2-dz+e 
$$
Implies not that $bz^3+dz = 0$ (although this also happens to be true), but that $b = 0$ and $d = 0$. So polynomials in your vector space are of the form
$$
az^4 +cz^2+e
$$
Then you can apply your second condition to get constraints on $a,c$ and $e$, but I'll leave that to you.